# Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, bucle-for, variables

Estoy intentando hacer un for loop para calcular el tamaño del efecto de dos tratamientos de temperatura sobre el área de semillas. Un tratamiento de temperatura corresponde a una generación y el otro tratamiento a otra.

Para eso armé el siguiente código:

```
sa <- subset(seedsarea2, select= -c(Rep))

f1 <- c("18-18", "24-18", "18-24", "24-24")
f2 <- c("18-18", "24-18", "18-24", "24-24")
Prom <- c(seedsarea2$Prom)

for (a in f1){
  A<- sa[sa$F1 == a,]
  
  for (b in f2){
    B<- A[A$F2 == b,]
    
    for (pm in Prom){
      C<- B[B$F1 %in% c("Prom", pm),]
         C<- droplevels(C)
      
      mfit<- Anova(glm(Prom ~ F1*F2, data=C, family = gaussian), type = 3,
                   contrasts = list(F1 = contr.sum))
      bm<- rbind(bm, cbind(a, b, m1, Chisq=mfit[1], Pr=mfit[3]))
    }
  }
}

pm<-c(bm[,4])
adjpm<-p.adjust(pm,method="holm")
(bm<-cbind(bm,adjpm))
write.csv(bm,"MatEffect.csv")
```

probé varias formas de armar el loop y siempre me tira el mismo error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :    contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Lo que probé fue:

```
for (a in f1){
  A<- seedsarea2[seedsarea2$F1 == a,]
  
  for (b in f2){
    B<- A[A$F2 == b,]

        mfit<- Anova(glm(F1~F2, data=B, family = gaussian), type = 3,
                 contrasts = list(F2 = contr.sum))
    bm<- rbind(bm, cbind(a, b, Chisq=mfit[1], Pr=mfit[3]))
  }
}
```

y también:

```
for(a in f2){
  A<- seedsarea2[seedsarea2$F2 == a,]
  
  for (pm in Prom){
    B<- A[A$Prom == pm,]
    
    fitM<-Anova(glm(Prom~F2, data = B, family = gaussian), type = 3,
                contrasts=list(F2=contr.sum))
    n<-rbind(n, cbind(a, pm, Chisq=fitM[1], Pr=fitM[3]))
  }
}
```

Encontré [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r) donde explican que este error ocurre cuando un factor tiene un solo nivel, el tema es que en mi caso, tanto F1 como F2 tienen 4 niveles y no entiendo porqué sólo me lee el primer nivel de cada factor cuando lo corro en R.

Actualización: corrí `traceback()` y me devolvió lo siguiente

```
> traceback()
6: stop("contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels")
5: `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])
4: model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts)
3: model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
2: glm(Prom ~ F2, data = B, family = gaussian)
1: Anova(glm(Prom ~ F2, data = B, family = gaussian), type = 3)
```

Comment: Sin ver un extracto de los datos, no podría dar una respuesta. Pero veo que estás aplicando dos condiciones lógicas `seedsarea2$F1 == a` y `A$F2 == b`. ¿Eso no es seleccionar uno de los niveles factoriales de F1 y F2?

Comment: Claro, quiero seleccionar de a uno los niveles y que haga una comparación de todos con todos

Comment: Pero si seleccionas de a un nivel por vez entonces no se cumple el supuesto que F2 deba tener al menos dos niveles.